# access to public PHP static property

Tags: php, object, static

During debugging I have stripped the class down, retaining the problem that I cannot get a value either outside the class or within (at the return statement) using

```
_SITE::$cfg;
```

though

```
self::$cfg
```

is correct there

```
class _SITE {
     public static $cfg;

     public static function cfg_add($newcfg) {
            self::$cfg = $newcfg;
            return self::$cfg;
     }
}
```

From gratefully received answers I need to clarify that this value is required to be changed / added to as an array.
Amended example - so its a static class holding property $cfg which its intended to access using _SITE::$cfg and update using _SITE::cfg_add

Comment: [What exactly is the problem](https://3v4l.org/Oj51a)?

Comment: I cannot seem to assign a value to _SITE::$cfg

Comment: https://eval.in/571769

Comment: I dont exactly get what you are trying to do, you like to assign value to _SITE::$cfg?

Comment: Amended example - so its a static class holding property $cfg which its intended to access using _SITE::$cfg and update using _SITE::cfg_add

Comment: Hey dude using singleton? You'r doin it wrong

Comment: @mike this would be an acceptable answer if you could elaborate - using MVC alternative would be to create another model and instantiate it as a property of the controller ?

Comment: I guess. Using statics like that is just another form of procedural programming. Unless you don't care and don't unit test your app. There's plenty of resources on the net already about IoC and DI.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get directly the value of the class _SITE instance, that way, because you never set yet a value for that instance.

but to get the value of `$cfg` given your code, and also notice the method `cfg_add()` assigned an array values.

Do it in this way

```
class _SITE {
   public static $cfg;

   public function __construct($value=array()) {
     self::$cfg = $value;
   }

   public static function cfg_add() {
     self::$cfg = array(1, 2, 3);
      return self::$cfg;
   }
}

$test =  _SITE::cfg_add();
foreach ($test as $key => $value) {
  echo "$value";
}
```

or in this way

```
$obj = new _SITE(array(1,2,3));
foreach ($obj::$cfg; as $key => $value) {
  echo "$value";
}
```

Comment: The class is intended to be used statically so __construct is not used

Comment: It's up to you, its just an example base on your code, but the way you access instance will give you empty. You need to have a class setter before you'll get the the value of _SITE::$cfg.

Answer (score 0):

No alternative but to create an instance of this class, as it contains data a controller references it was made to inherit a model class.